# Modx Search Features

Tags: search, modx

How could I create a search feature in Modx that would limit the returned results based on what the user selects from some predetermined search criteria. Such as: "Color", "Size", "Model".

So that a user who selects: "Blue", "Large", "AZ84" would see a list of items with model number AZ84 that are large and blue.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking ModX Evolution - you can do it with Ditto.
See 'request extender' : http://ditto.modxcms.com/extenders/request.html

You can also wrap it with your own snippet to get the get/post, validate it and build the results via a *runSnippet* call to Ditto.

if you need more specific stuff (like date ranges, etc..) you can do it with simple extenders for custom filtering and sorting.  (look in /assets/snippets/ditto/extenders/example.extender.inc.php)